# How to configure Kamailio or OpenSIPS as Session Border Controller?

Tags: voip, freeswitch, kamailio, opensips, fusionpbx

Beginner here, just a simple student project, not production oriented. I can use other open-source, i gave just an example as Kamailio or OpenSIPS.

internal FreeSWITCH 192.168.86.165---192.168.86.169 SBC 192.168.253.169---192.168.253.130 external FreeSWITCH

How can i implement a open-source SBC to work like the one in the figure with mainly only security and routing features, the most simple it can be? And what is the logic of SBC? FS1 will trunk to SBC or to FS2 and FS2 will use the domain and port of FS1 or SBC's when initialising calls?

I've also tried to install LibreSBC, tinySBC but installation doesn't work, that's why i've stopped for Kamailio and OpenSIPS. kamailio.cfg overwhelms me with 1000 lines of configuration and i can't understand how much should i overwrite of default configs when i add new routing lines

Comment: SBC config usually above 10000 lines. If you have problem with 1000, that is not your class task. Default config is NOT  config for SBC.

Comment: As option you can check Wazo or kazoo projects.

Comment: Your question is like "I want to build to supercar, I have checked some childs carts and they have 10000+ parts. How I can build a supercar?"